# Apache FTP Client inconsistencies and file with DES encoding

Tags: security, apache, ftp, cryptography, encryption

Using the Apache FTP client I am downloading a file. As per already existing logic, this gets decoded using the Cipher class

This is what I am using

> Cipher cipher =
>   Cipher.getInstance("DES/CBC/NoPadding")

I am facing 2 issues:

1. The file the apache client downloads is different from the the file that I download using another client (FileZilla) . Initially I thought it might be an incomplete file, but I do see a line in the file which says

> end

Can I consider this a complete file ?

1. If I were to encrypt the same file twice separately, using the same algorithm, would I get the same resultant file both the times. (I know this is trivial, but I am new to encryption)

Thanks,
Priya

Answer (score 0):

> If I were to encrypt the same file
>   twice separately, using the same
>   algorithm, would I get the same
>   resultant file both the times. (I know
>   this is trivial, but I am new to
>   encryption)

Not necessarily, when using CBC mode you must specify an Initialization Vector (or it may generate a random one). This is a one time peice of data that is XOR'd with the first block of plain data before being encrypted with the symmetric key. The result is that a peice of data, or a file, encrypted with the same algorithm, but different IV, will result in different cipher text. It's the same concept as using a salt for hashes. You can use ECB mode which does not use an initialization vector, but is obviously less secure.

That being said, if you were to encrypt file A, with initialization vector A. Then encrypt file A again, with initialization vector B. Then decrypt both using the appropraite initialization vectors, you should recieve the exact same file as the original, byte for byte.

Comment: Thanks Petey ! That helps me understand at least a part of the problem